# Discord.js Bot repeats the same welcome message

Tags: discord, discord.js

How do I prevent the bot from sending the same welcome message twice in a row? I think it has something to do with defining the server message intent.

client.on('guildMemberAdd', (member) => {

client.channels.cache.get('channelID').send("welcome");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed the parentheses from `client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {`

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this might help:-

```
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    member.guild.channels.get('channelID').send("Welcome"); 
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Should I be defining any intents? Changing it to member.guild didn't yield any welcome message at all.

Comment: I think it might work if you replace ```member.guild.channels``` by ```client.channels.cache```.

Comment: It still sends the same message twice. I've tried
`member.guild.channels.cache.get` and `member.client.channels.cache.get`
There's only one running process.